# How can I turn a <textarea> into a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

One example would be on any YouTube video while not being signed in. If you click the 'textarea' to type a comment, it'll act as a link and send you to the sign in page. How can this be done?

When I hover over the textarea in the image

[image]

The entire box acts as a clickable link as if it were an anchor tag.

Comment: Please elaborate more.

Comment: **Bind** a `click` event handler to a `textarea` element and on the click event you can redirect the user to login page.

Comment: above me is the answer

Comment: one addition to @gurvinder372  comment is:- on click first check user is logged-in or not, if not then redirect to other page or show the link (which is hide initially), and hide the textarea

Comment: may I have a code example, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below is only an example.

You have to check whether the user is logged in using php, and save it in a cookie and then make the calculation using jQuery.

Do not use `id` to check if the user is logged in, because it is not secured. If the user inspects, and removes the id, he will be able to write in the box without logging in.

To redirect the user, instead of using `alert`, use `window.location.href = ''`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#isNotLogged").click(function() {
     $("#isNotLogged").blur();
    alert('Please login');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="isLogged" placeholder="Textarea for Logged in"></textarea>
<br />

<textarea id="isNotLogged" placeholder="Textarea for Not Logged in"></textarea>
```